# Extending the MefModuleManager

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism, mef, prism-4

I want to extend the MefModuleManager. Now I am searching for a way to do this.
First I have created my own ModuleManager:

```
public class MyModuleManager : MefModuleManager {
    public MyModuleManager(IModuleInitializer moduleInitializer, IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, ILoggerFacade loggerFacade) : base(moduleInitializer, moduleCatalog, loggerFacade) {
    }

    protected override void HandleModuleTypeLoadingError(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, Exception exception) {
        // ... my Code
    }
}
```

Now, In my Shell I have (like described in Prism with Mef):

```
// The shell imports IModuleManager once to load modules on-demand.
// Due to SilverLight/MEF restrictions this must be public.
[Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
public IModuleManager ModuleManager
```

I don't know, how to tell Mef, that It should use `MyModuleManager` instead of `MefModuleManager` for `IModuleManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the **MefBootStrapper** use different dependencies, you need to declare your custom classes with the **[Export]** attribute.

Then, if you want **Mef** to use your custom **ModuleManager** for a specific type class, you may add a parameter on the attribute for specifying the dependency type which would be resolved as follows:

```
[Export(typeof(IModuleManager))]
public class MyModuleManager : MefModuleManager
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyModuleManager(IModuleInitializer moduleInitializer, IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, ILoggerFacade loggerFacade) : base(moduleInitializer, moduleCatalog, loggerFacade) {
    }

    protected override void HandleModuleTypeLoadingError(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, Exception exception) {
        // ... my Code
    }
}
```

Notice that I have added an **[ImportingConstructor]** attribute so the **BootStrapper** would be able to pass the requested arguments when initializing. That way, **Mef** would use your custom **ModuleManager** when a request is made for an **IModuleManager** instance.

You can refer to the following **MSDN Prism Guide** chapter for more information:

- [3: Managing Dependencies Between Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec6)

I hope this helped, regards.